# Cumulocity HTML widget

Tags: cumulocity

I am trying to use the inbuilt HTML widget to render a google map.

But the plugin is showing as unsupported/image is not getting loaded.Is there a list of supported plugins available for HTML widget?

Alternatively I tried to insert a gif image also, which was not rendered.

Does cumulocity html widget supports gif?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried checking the *"Allow insecure use of elements and attributes"* option?

[image: Screenshot of the html widget options]

In general, everything you tried to achive should work.

Could you provide some more details, e.g. screenshots or you html code?

Comment: I am trying to use the leaflet js and I am trying to create a map showing the location of the ISS (common example I found in youtube). Main aim is to invoke API using fetch() function. The map is getting rendered in a standalone browser but not getting rendered in HTML widget.

Comment: It seems that Cumulocity JS engine does not support keywords like "const". I had to change to "var". Also within the same same dashboard, I had another HTML widget where I had same div id and map variable name. I changed them and it is now loading. It seems like it is considering the entire dashboard as a single object and hence duplicate variable or element names/id is causing issue. Can you please confirm?